# Javascript + jquery checkbox validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I have to validate the checkbox.

```
if($("#update_user_modal #room1").attr('checked', false)) room1Val = 0;
```

This is working fine. But I have to check if it is not checked also. The else method wont work.

```
if($("#update_user_modal #room1").attr('checked', true)) room1Val = 1;
```

This is working also.

BUT! When i use both like this:

```
  if ($("#update_user_modal #room1").attr('checked', false)) room1Val = 0;

  if($("#update_user_modal #room1").attr('checked', true)) room1Val = 1;
```

it works just sometimes.

I tried with .prop also.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not *reading* the attribute value, but *writing* it. Don't use the second argument to `attr` -- only use one:

```
room1Val = +$("#update_user_modal #room1").attr('checked'))
```

This will do the two cases in one go, since it returns a boolean. The `+` makes that a 0 or 1.

Secondly, it is better to use `prop` over `attr` for this case:

```
room1Val = +$("#update_user_modal #room1").prop('checked'))
```

Comment: Your answer is better than theirs ;)

Answer (score 1):

JQuery: Use `.is(':checked')`

```
if ($("#update_user_modal #room1").is(':checked') room1Val = 0;
 else room1Val = 1;
```

Javascript: use `.checked` property of a checkbox.

```
if document.getElementById('chkboxName').checked room1Val = 0;
 else room1Val = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `is(":checked")` option.

Your code would look like this:

```
if (!$("#update_user_modal #room1").is(":checked")) room1Val = 0;

if($("#update_user_modal #room1").is(":checked")) room1Val = 1;
```

Check [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/%20documentation) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a
>   boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if
>   the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute
>   has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is
>   true of all boolean attributes.
>
> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property:

```
if ( elem.checked )
if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
```

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score -1):

You should do it like below:

```
if ($("#update_user_modal #room1").prop('checked')) {
    room1Val = 1;
} else {
    room1Val = 0;
}
```